# CI common practices for docker + helm monorepo?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I have a git repo for a project, which contains both the Dockerfile (in the root directory)and the helm chart (under `chart/`). The versioning of the docker image and the helm repo are separate, with the following requirements:

- if the application code is changed, a new (semver) version of the docker image must be built and pushed, and a new version of the helm chart (`version` in `Chart.yaml`), referencing the new image tag (`appVersion` in `Chart.yaml`), must be packaged and pushed
- if the helm chart itself is changed (eg changes in templates), a new version of the chart (`version` in `Chart.yaml`) must also be packaged and pushed.

Changes might happen directly in the `master` branch, or in a branch that is subsequently merged into master, so I imagine the above actions have to happen either upon push to master, or upon merges into master (in both cases, there might be a testing phase prior to the build, but I think this doesn't change the problem).

First of all, is the above setup the common practice?
Second, I'm not sure about where to save versions. I've read that saving versions in the repo (eg with a `VERSIONS` file or something) is bad practice, so I was thinking of using git tags, but how? We'd need two series of tags, one for the image and the other for the chart, is it how people do that? Or how would one go about this? Also, where should the version bump happen? Is it normal to have the CI pipeline itself do the bump and commit? Or should it come from the committer?

Thinking out loud, I would like to avoid having the CI do commits and pushes, because I fear that people would then forget to pull and would do local commits before, which would in turn pollute the git history with merges.
So one idea, if going with the automatic version bumping, could be to store the versions in a database or external storage and have the CI pipeline retrieve them, do the necessary bumping and then store them again. In this case I suppose I would have to establish a rule for bumping, for example always bump the patch version. Is this common practice, at least in some scenarios?
If instead we let the developers choose when and what to bump, how do they communicate that? (even in this case, there's still an automated part: when the docker image has been bumped, the helm chart version should be bumped automatically) I've read about conventional commits, but still, they don't store the actual versions. Where do I store the image and chart versions? Should I make them use tags? (but then, two separate series? How?)

Sorry if this all sounds confused, but that's because I am too.
This is my first try at setting up CI for a repo and I'm struggling to find examples, so I'm thinking that I'm either using a wrong approach or missing something obvious.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're using semantic versioning, how do you determine whether a code change is a breaking change, adding a new interface, or neither?  Does the Helm chart have to be republished with the new image tag?  This seems very broad to me, and I'm unclear that there's a universal best practice with a canonical implementation.

Comment: The helm chart has to be republished with the new image tags, and the helm chart version must also be bumped in that case. I hadn't thought about the scope of changes, but again, that's part of my confusion: if it's done automatically, I suppose I'd have to pick a scheme (eg always bump the patch, or something), on the other hand if the committer can choose, they'll pick whatever they deem appropriate, won't they?